# Bind an action when a button is clicked in jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a strange problem, i'm binding an action to a button using the jQuery function (click), when i click the button nothing happens, how that come!, here's the code i'm using:    `

```
<script >
    $( '#admin' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
    $('#AddButton').click(function(){
            alert("Clicked")
        });​
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the button exists in the initial page source you need to either:

1. Put your `<script>` block somewhere in the source after the button, or
2. Wrap the above code in a `$(document).ready()` handler.

Otherwise the button's html will not have been parsed by the browser when the JS runs so the button won't be found.

If the button does not exist initially, i.e., you are adding it dynamically in response to some other event, then you can use:

```
$('#AddButton').live('click', function(){ ...
```

...similar to what you're already doing for your `admin` element and the handler will automatically apply to the button once it does exist.

Note though that `.live()` is deprecated from jQuery version 1.7 onwards so if using 1.7 you should use the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead, and even in older jQuery the [`.delegate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is preferred. The [API doco for `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) explains how to convert.

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot to mention in my answer that if you are adding the button dynamically your other option is to run the `.click()` binding from the part of the code where you add the button.